# Using latex formulas in astro using markdown and katex: How may I centered the formulas?

Tags: markdown, astrojs, katex, remarkjs

I'm trying to create a blog with mathematical formulas in Latex using Astro, with posts in Markdown.

Following the instructions from [this blog](https://ileumas.com/writing/2022/03/astro-math-katex/), I've created a minimal example project at [this Github repository](https://github.com/pdenapo/astro-latex-example).

However, as you can see [here](https://astro-latex-example.vercel.app/formula) the displayed formula

```markdown
$$ \int_0^\infty = \frac{1}{x^2+1} \;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}  $$
```

is not centered as it should.

I've found that This problem is related to CSS. Indeed if I could apply a class to the paragraph containing the formula, I can fix it. Indeed the following work-around works:

```markdown
$$ \int_0^\infty = \frac{1}{x^2+1} \;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}  $$

<style>
 p {
      text-align: center;  
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that doing so, would affect all the paragraphs on the page. And I cannot do something like

```
<span class="formula">
$$ \int_0^\infty = \frac{1}{x^2+1} \;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}  $$
</span>
```

since this breaks remark-math parsing!

Also, using the katex \htmlClass function does not work,
since this acts in the children element of the paragraph,
and not in the paragraph itself.

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This will center your element. Looking at the html, it looks like this because of how katex renders the html, but I have no idea. I just know I threw these two attributes on your p tag and worked.

[image]